# Значение слов КРУГОДАЛЬ, КРУГОХОД

Tags: словообразование, значение-слов, окказионализмы

**1. Текст песни Тревоги одной лисицы** (автора не знаю)

***Кругодаль*** заслонила красками
Перешеек и радугу леса
За кострами, полями опасными
Нахожу части рассвета
**[Тревоги одной лисицы](http://www.jooov.net/text/162868705/VerMat-revogi_odnoy_lisitsyi.htmls)**

**2**."...Близстоящие суслики криво покосились на медвежьи попытки вписаться в общий ***кругоход***. Тогда он перестал двигать лапой и отошел в сторонку..."
**[Борис Кригер, "Медведка"](https://books.google.ee/books?id=E32sAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA687&lpg=PA687&dq=%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=xmWOKX3l4O&sig=aq5gYv7JHfEHg3rUyfsiejU0IaQ&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO49WymbTTAhVCWiwKHWSoDZYQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8&f=false)**

В словообразовательном и толковом словарях значений не нашла, хотя общий смысл мне, конечно, понятен.
А что знаете-предполагаете-думаете Вы?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что кругодаль очень даже красивое, ёмкое по образности слово. Есть очень много нюансов мировосприятия, которые ещё ждут своего описания, своего нового словесного обозначения. Кроме того, мне видится, что, когда мы слышим слова "горизонт", "даль", или исконно славянское слово "небосклон", то говорящий воспринимается нашим подсознанием как однонаправленно стоящий или идущий. Если же говорящий выбрал слово "кругодаль", то он представляется нам, как  стоящий на возвышенности, который имеет возможность одним беспрерывным взором (пройдя по кругу или повернув голову) охватить, все стороны горизонта, он как бы осмысляет себя центром вселенной.

Comment: Согласна с Вами, МарМанукян.  "Удивительность" и нестандартность,  какой-то космический размах ,  объемная  "красивость" и нежность одновременно. Кругодаль - особенное слово.